# Is it worth completely replacing my track wheelset?

Tags: wheels, single-speed

I own and commute on a 2009 KHS Flite100, bought used. Since purchasing it, I have spent around $250 getting it up to scratch, with new tires, pedals, saddle, and other small but worthwhile upgrades.

Recently, I have noticed a rattling noise coming from the rear hub whenever I pedal. I have not been able to replicate this noise at the bike shop, but after a quick inspection I have been told that the hub has been overtightened, and will need to be disassembled. This will take my bike, used for daily commutes, out of commission for a couple of days, and cost me an estimated $50. That being said, I suspect that the problem is going to, in the end, cost me a new hub.

It seems to be common knowledge amongst cyclists that the most worthwhile major upgrade for a bike is a new set of wheels. Unfortunately, while the value and quality of standard road wheelsets has been well documented by various reliable sources, there seems to be very little information pertaining to track, or single speed wheelsets. I am finding it very difficult to separate genuine quality upgrades from primarily aesthetic ones.

My bike came stock with a pair of Weinmann DP17s and unbranded hubs. I would like to know if it is worth upgrading the wheels instead of having the hub rebuilt, and if so, what I should buy. I would prefer to pay less than $250, but I can (sort of) justify paying more if it's going to have a significant improvement on the general ride quality of my bike.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately many of the mainstream wheel companies don't offer a SS.  And you don't want a track wheel. You see the Velocity Chucker rim used a lot as it is pretty ballistic.    Hub and spokes is what you are willing to pay.   You get what you pay for.  A good $400 wheelset is a step up from $250.  But my local fixie shop sells some decent wheelsets for for $225.

Comment: I'd put a set of DP18s on there and ride. $119 at velomine.com. But what is probably bad on your current wheel are the bearings. Phil Wood bearings are excellent and are $14 and an easy swap - takes an hour max, a properly equipped shop can knock it out in 30 minutes. Good luck.

Comment: I spoke with the shop's mechanic, and he told me, after completely overhauling the hub, that it's not going to last much longer. The cones and bearings are badly worn, and the axle is slightly bent. That being said, for something that came with the five year old bike, it has held up admirably.

Comment: I'm currently looking at a wheelset from Wabi cycles - $250, 1700 grams and, as far as I can tell, positive reviews. Shipping might be a hassle, but we'll see. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Hi Rob - this question is old, and has no answer.  Would you like to post and accept your own new answer describing how it has gone for you in the past 8 months?  Did you buy a new wheel or did you buy a new hub and rebuild the wheel?